# Moderators deleting comments?

Tags: discussion, migration, comments

Whenever a SO question is migrated, it has a few comments that say "Belongs on SU" or the like.

This confuses the heck out of me because when I read a question, I read the question, then the comments, then I stare at it in wonder (since it's already on SuperUser), and then I scroll down and go "Ohhh...it was migrated...".

Is there any way that we can filter out these comments or <s>force</s> let the moderators delete them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, flag them for moderator attention by clicking the little flag icon next to the comment.

Comment: I generally flag them as noise

Comment: Wait, wasn't there an automatic punishment involved if 6 or so people flag the comment?

Comment: @bobby that is only for posts, there is no -100 for comments, but it can be auto-removed

Comment: I see, Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Like Jeff said, continue to flag comments that are migration noise.  We do make efforts to clean up migrated questions as we catch them coming into the site.  Moderator flags help us find them quicker.